# Unity tutorial(Space Shooter), C# NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working through the 'Space Shooter' tutorial on the unity website([here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/space-shooter-tutorial)) and I am having trouble with the following code. I am attempting to put constraints on the ships `Rigidbody` such that it can't leave the visible game area. However, I am getting the following error, and I can't see why(this is literally my first time using C# also, so sorry if it's really obvious what's wrong):

**Error:**

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerController.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:28)
```

I have marked line 28(mentioned in the error) below

**Script:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Boundary 
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;
}

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public float speed;
    public Boundary b;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
        rb.velocity = movement * speed;

        rb.position = new Vector3(  \\ *** line 28 ***
            Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.x, b.xMin, b.xMax),
            0.0f,
            Mathf.Clamp (rb.position.z, b.zMin, b.zMax)
        );

    }
}
```

Any help with resolving this error is much appreciated, the script in the tutorial itself isn't compatible with unity5 it seems, but I just don't see how this error is right.

Comment: should I have done b = new Boundary or something like that?

Comment: I don't know, I have no idea where you want and or need to initialize the thing. But yes, you need to create a new Boundary somewhere and assign it to the field. Unless you do that, it will remain null.

Comment: Aha, I think I have it now. I needed to initialize it with b = new Boundary(), which I did in the Start function. I hadn't actually thought about it until your comment though, so thanks!

Comment: Why was this downvoted? If you leave a comment I could improve the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mention in the comments, you are not initializing `b` anywhere, so it's `null` by default. Read up on default values and stuff [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and also take a look at the difference between value types and reference types, as there is for example a way to make your `Boundary` a value type.

You might also want to add a constructor to your `Boundary` so that it's easier to create one.

```
public class Boundary 
{
    public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax;

    public Boundary(float xMin, float xMax, ...)
    {
          // Set your fields.
    }
}
```

And even better, use Unity's `Vector2` type to store your boundary info.

```
public class Boundary 
{
    public Vector2 MinPoint;
    public Vector2 MaxPoint;

    public Boundary(Vector2 minPoint, Vector2 maxPoint)
    {
          MinPoint = minPoint;
          MaxPoint = maxPoint;
    }
}
```

Writing this snippet was significantly less painful than writing the first. If you really don't need anything other than a way to store those 4 coordinates, take a look at `Rect` [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html), because it kind of has what you want already.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `Boundary` is a reference type, meaning that if you don't give it an value, it is null. And in your code, I can't see you ever assigned `b` a value. That is why a `NullReferenceException` occurs -- `b` is null! Maybe you can do this in the start method:

```
b = new Boundary ();
b.xMin = 1;
b.xMax = 2;
b.zMin = 3;
b.zMax = 4;
//The numbers are just examples. Change it however you want
```

And that should make `b` not null. Or, you can add a constructor in the `Boundary` class:

```
public Boundary (int xMin, int xMax, int zMin, int zMax) {
    this.xMin = xMin;
    this.xMax = xMax;
    this.zMin = zMin;
    this.zMax = zMax;
}
```